# Dedekind Cut and Real Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In defining real numbers with a Dedekind Cut there is an issue that continues to confuse me. Suppose we perform a Dedekind cut on the number line, and we look at say the left set of rationals. (Where the left set is the complement of the Right set on Q) Is a real number defined as being the infinite Left set of rationals or is it defined as being the least upper bound of that set. (I.e. the cut itself)  In what I have read it is unclear as to me which it is, and sometimes seems like it’s given as either one. What bothers me here is that it would seem that both cant serve as a definition as they are not equivalent. I.e. the least upper bound is a distinct non-equivalent object from the left set. In very general terms, if B and C are not equivalent that it would seem that both cannot serve as a definition for A.

Comment: can you say exactly where you have seen a real number defined as the least upper bound of a Dedekind cut?  This doesn't make any sense on the face of it (where would this least upper bound come from if you haven't already defined the real numbers!)

Comment: You cannot define the real numbers by defining them as the "least upper bound" of the left set, because there may be no such object: real numbers don't "exist" yet! You only have the rationals to play with. The real numbers are defined to be the set of Dedekind cuts themselves; you can then identify the rational numbers with *some* of those cuts; depending on precisely how you define them, either the ones in which the left seet has a maximum; or the ones in which the right set has a minimum.

Comment: You can implement a sorting algorithm in several different ways which are equivalent in runtime or memory use. In what sense those are different "sortings"? The point of Dedekind cuts is to show that there is a way to do things. Not that it's **the only way** to do things.

Comment: One resolution of your confusion is that **after** the real numbers have been defined using the Dedekind cuts themselves (as in the comment of @ArturoMagidin), one can then go on to prove a theorem: There is a unique injection $i : \mathbb Q \hookrightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for any Dedekind cut of $\mathbb Q$, the real number corresponding to that Dedekind cut is equal to the least upper bound of (the $i$ image of) the left set of the given cut.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are perfectly valid constructions:

When identifying a rational number with the 'left side' of a Dedekind cut, for example

$$ r=\sqrt{2} $$
$$\mbox{ is defined by the `left set' of rationals } A, $$
$$ A=\{ a\in\mathbb{Q}: a^2 < 2 \mbox{ or } a < 0 \} $$
so that
$$ \sqrt{2} = \{ a\in\mathbb{Q}: a^2 < 2 \mbox{ or } a < 0 \} ,$$
we need to define arithmetic  operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division), say as follows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_by_Dedekind_cuts

Then you just show that
$$ A \times A=2 \mbox{ where } 2 = \{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x<2\}$$
which boils down to finding a sequence in $A$ whose squares get arbitrarily close to  $2$.

So at the end of it all, what comes out is still your `least upper bound' idea, just watching out that we are rigorous when defining numbers and their arithmetic as a set